Powertrain modeling for video games
I have been working on a driving game in Unity for some time now, mostly working on the tyre model. I have essentially "completed" the tyre model and I have a relatively realistic model that works for my purposes and is stable.
I have made a sort of powertrain before, but it wasn't very realistic, nor was the code all that great as it was highly coupled.
I would like to have a system of abstract PowertrainComponents that can essentially just slot together and work as expected. This way I can model lots of different types of vehicles in a more straightforward way (having differentials connected to other differentials like a AWD car, or the engine connected directly to the transmission without a coupling like some electric cars etc.), but I don't even really know how to structure my code where to begin.
How can I structure my code so that I can make modular, relatively realistic engine models for my game?

In coding terms, there are multiple ways to solve this problem. At a fundamental level, you need one "socket" that fits multiple plugs.
Two ways to approach this are "polymorphism" and "interfaces".
Intefaces
An interface is effectively a definition for the plug/socket that both sides agree to comply with...
public interface IEngine {
    public void SetThrottle(float value); // A method to set the throttle
    public float PowerOutput { get; } // And a read-only property to read power output

}

Then your GameObject/class/code would refer to a generic engine as IEngine...
IEngine engine;

void Start() {
    engine = new TestEngine();
}

void Update() {
    engine.SetThrottle(...);
}

Now all your engines need to do is implement the IEngine interface...
If you type
public class TestEngine : IEngine {

}

Visual Studio will prompt you to auto-scaffold the methods for you, and you can fill out the rest.
public class TestEngine : IEngine {
    float throttle = 0;

    public void SetThrottle(float value) {
        throttle = value;
    }

    public float PowerOutput => throttle * 2;
    
}

This is clean and completely decoupled. It's a good choice if the code for each engine is small and unique.
If there's a lot of overlap between different engines (let's say you need a "calculateAirVolume" method in each, or similar) then polymorphism is a better option.
Polymorphism (aka Inheritance)
This also follows the plug/socket paradigm, except instead of the definition being the interface, it's a special type of class (an "abstract" class) that contains all the shared code and defines the common methods.
public abstract class EngineBase {
    public void SetThrottle(float value) {
        throttle = value;
    }
    public abstract float PowerOutput { get; } // A read-only property to read power output
    float DoSomeCommonCalculation() {
        return PowerOutput * 3;
    }
    protected float throttle;
}

And methods or properties that are marked "abstract" will have to be implemented by every engine, everything marked "protected" is considered "common" and available to the EngineBase and any engines that "derive" from it. Anything with no access modified (or marked private) will be accessible only to the EngineBase, not any derived engines.
This time you implement your code to reference an EngineBase rather than an IEngine
public class TestEngine : EngineBase {
    public override float PowerOutput => throttle * 2;
}

Again, Visual Studio will auto-complete the scaffolding for you, but this time any of the methods in your TestEngine class can call SomeCommonCalculation() and refer to Throttle.
Any time you need to refer to an engine, always refer to it as an IEngine/EngineBase as appropriate and they'll all work interchangeably.
Another reading topic which might be useful is "Inversion of Control" also known as "Dependency Injection".

Yes I done something like this in which i have an abstract engine, transmission and differential class, however its still tightly coupled. The engine needs to know about the transmission, the transmission needs to know about the differential. It works, but its not very realistic. Im looking for a more realistic way of solving this, where each powertrainComponent has its own angular velocity and inertia, and i can essentially add any component as an input or output of any other component. Eg, i can have a differential output to 2 other differentials  and it just works as expected.

The above design is still suitable, but you need to delve into that further reading I suggested. Inversion of Control basically means that the engine doesn't know what's downstream of it, it's just handed an ITransmission (or IDriveChainComponent or whatever) as part of its constructor. Whether that's really a transmission or a fly wheel is irrelevant, it'll just take the "thing" and act on it. Makes unit testing trivially simple, too.

https://www.infoworld.com/article/2255952/how-to-use-inversion-of-control-in-c.html - Skip down to "Invert the control using dependency injection" to see how they're doing it with a logging class.
